Chrome extension automatically click a button when it appears?
I am trying to click automatically a "don't logout button" when it appears.
I managed to click it manually with a popup in the chrome-extension.
But it would be nice if the button will be clicked as soon it appears, and additionally when the tab isn't the active tab or chrome/edge isn't the active window.
My manifest.json:
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "TEST",
    "version": "4.0",
    "permissions": ["activeTab"],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}

My Popup.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Extension</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, Extension!</h1>
    <button id="dismissButton">Dismiss</button>

    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

and my popup.js:
document.getElementById('dismissButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: `document.querySelector('.btn.abc-btn.abc-btn-blue').click();`
    });
})
function isDismissButtonVisible() {
    const dismissButton = document.querySelector('.btn.abc-btn.abc-btn-blue');
    return dismissButton && window.getComputedStyle(dismissButton).display !== 'none';
}

function clickDismissButton() {
    const dismissButton = document.querySelector('.btn.abc-btn.abc-btn-blue');
    if (dismissButton) {
        dismissButton.click();
    }
}

const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if (isDismissButtonVisible()) {
        clickDismissButton();
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
}, 10000);

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
    if (tab.title === 'abc Reliance') {
        clickDismissButton();
    }
});


This was my second not working approach:
Manifest.json:
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Button Watcher Extension",
    "version": "1.2",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs"],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["*abc.com/*"],
            "js": ["content.js"],
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }

}

popup.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Button Watcher Extension</title>
    <style>
        /* Add any custom CSS styles for your popup here */
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #countdown {
            font-size: 24px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Click Button</h3>
    <h4 id="present">presentyn</h4>
    <button id="dismissButton">Dismiss</button>
    <p id="countdown">secondsLeft</p> <!-- Display the countdown here -->

    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

Content.js:
document.getElementById('dismissButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
         code: `document.querySelector('.btn.abc-btn.abc-btn-blue').click();`
    });
});


function isDismissButtonVisible() {
    let presentyn = 'no'; 
    const dismissButton = document.querySelector("#gbqfbb"); 
    
    
    if (dismissButton && window.getComputedStyle(dismissButton).display !== 'none') {
        presentyn = 'yes';
    }
    displaypresent(presentyn);
    return presentyn; 
}

function clickDismissButton() {
    const dismissButton = document.querySelector('.btn.abc-btn.abc-btn-blue');
    if (dismissButton) {
        dismissButton.click();
    }
}

function waitOneSecond() {
     setTimeout(function() {
        displayCountdown(secondsLeft);       
    }, 1000); 
}


function startCountdown() {
    let secondsLeft = 3;

    
    displayCountdown(secondsLeft);
    

    
    const countdownInterval = setInterval(() => {
        secondsLeft--;
        displayCountdown(secondsLeft);

        if (secondsLeft === 0) {
            secondsLeft = 0;
            displayCountdown(secondsLeft);
            waitOneSecond();
            clearInterval(countdownInterval); 
            isDismissButtonVisible();
            if (presentyn='yes') {
                clickDismissButton();   
            }
            startCountdown();
        }
    }, 200);
}


function displayCountdown(seconds) {
    const countdownElement = document.getElementById('countdown');
    countdownElement.innerText = seconds;
}

function displaypresent(valuep) {
    const presentElement = document.getElementById('present');
    presentElement.innerText = valuep;
}

startCountdown();

content.js:



const buttonSelector = '.btn.abc-btn.abc-btn-blue';


function clickButton() {
    const button = document.querySelector(buttonSelector);
    if (button) {
        button.click();
    }
}


function displayCountdown(seconds) {
    const countdownElement = document.getElementById('countdown');
    countdownElement.innerText = seconds;
}


function startCountdown() {
    let secondsLeft = 3;
    displayCountdown(secondsLeft);

    const countdownInterval = setInterval(() => {
        secondsLeft--;
        displayCountdown(secondsLeft);

        if (secondsLeft === 0) {
            clearInterval(countdownInterval);
            clickButton(); 
        }
    }, 1000); 
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    startCountdown();
});

const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    mutations.forEach((mutation) => {
        if (!mutation.addedNodes) return;

        for (const node of mutation.addedNodes) {
             if (node.matches("[class*='ui-dialog-content']")) {
                
                const buttonToClick = document.querySelector(buttonSelector);
                if (buttonToClick) {
                    buttonToClick.click();
                }
            }
        }
    });
});

observer.observe(document.body, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributes: false,
    characterData: false
});

background.js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { action: "clickButton" }, (response) => {
        if (response.success) {
            console.log("Button clicked successfully!");
        } else {
            console.log("Button not found.");
        }
    });
});

# Listen for tab changes
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener((activeInfo) => {
    const tabId = activeInfo.tabId;
    chrome.tabs.get(tabId, (tab) => {
        if (tab.url.includes("*://abc.com/*")):
            # Inject content script
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file: "content.js" }, () => {
                # Content script loaded
                console.log("Content script injected");
            });
    });
});

# Listen for messages from content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (message.buttonClicked):
        console.log("Button clicked!");
        # Do something after button click

EDIT Clarification about the use of the Add-On:
I have a website which logs me out every 2 minutes if there are no Action inside the site. Before the logout a warning window appears with the question if I am still there and the possibility to click on "dismiss" is given to prevent the logout.
Simultaneously I am working on other tabs and other programs except of edge.
During this work the Add-on should avoid the logoff from the website with pressing the "dismiss-button" as soon as the button appears.

Have you tried a mutation observer? https://building.lang.ai/hacking-with-dom-mutationobservers-348a50231580

If the goal is to click the button automatically then the only thing you need is a content script with MutationObserver inside, no need for the UI and other scripts. Could you clarify the overall workflow i.e. how the extension is used?

@wOxxOm I have added an clarification at the bottom

@connexo not yet

Looks like you only need content_scripts with MutationObserver inside, nothing else. There's just one caveat: if you want it to run immediately after reloading/installing the extension in Chrome you'll need to inject it explicitly.
